# Memory leak in java liferay project

Tags: java, postgresql, memory-leaks, liferay-6

When i try to re-deploy my project, sometimes it run out of memory and throw perGemSpace error (just re-deploy 2-3 times)
I know my project have some memory leak trouble but can't figure out, someone can expland to me please. :-?

```
Jan 14, 2013 1:12:21 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/qlbc-portlet] registered the JDBC driver [net.sf.log4jdbc.DriverSpy] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Jan 14, 2013 1:12:21 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/qlbc-portlet] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Jan 14, 2013 1:12:21 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/qlbc-portlet] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-43] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 14, 2013 1:12:21 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/qlbc-portlet] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-4] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 14, 2013 1:12:21 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/qlbc-portlet] appears to have started a thread named [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 14, 2013 1:12:21 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/qlbc-portlet] appears to have started a thread named [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 14, 2013 1:12:21 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/qlbc-portlet] appears to have started a thread named [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are not unregistering your drivers or stopping your threads.

If you don't manage these items well, you are likely to get memory leaks, such as this.